# javascript ternary if using condition's value as the outcome

Tags: javascript

In PHP, say if I have code like this:

```
$aValue = functionThatReturnsAValue(); // the function might return a string or null;
$anotherValue = $aValue ? process($aValue) : null;
```

only for brievity (IDK is this a good practice or not and also regarding the performance, etc), I used to change the code like so:

```
$anotherValue = ($aValue = functionThatReturnsAValue()) ? process($aValue) : null;
```

My questions are:

1. Is this style even a good practice?
2. How can I use this with JavaScript? I wrote with same style but got error.

Thank you.

Comment: What error? No, this is not good practice.

Comment: you have assignment in if statement, not a value. if you want to keep this in one line it would be better to write it like this : 
`$anotherValue =  functionThatReturnsAValue() ? process( functionThatReturnsAValue()) : null;`

Comment: The ternary operator does not help maintainability

Comment: @Xufox i have code like this `aValue: (let a = someFunction()) ? a : null,`. ESLint gave me Unexpected Token.

Comment: @rahmatNazali That code is completely different from what you posted, and syntactically invalid.

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko I definitely may be wrong, but this will run the `functionThatReturnsAValue()` twice, isn't it? Where we could only call it once and save the result on a tmp variable and use it again later. CMIIW

Comment: @Xufox I just tried to change it like so `let aValue = (let a = Constant.projectName) ? a : null` and I still got the same error. CMIIW

Comment: well yeah, that's true, it's better to keep value in a variable above, to be honest. By the way, you could check for null in `process()` function, and return null in this case, so you won't need this statement at all. 
`anotherValue = process(functionThatReturnsAValue());`

Comment: @rahmatNazali Well… it’s still syntactically invalid. You can’t put a `let` in expression context.

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko Thankyou for the kind reply. I have learned a lot from this.

Comment: @Xufox thankyou for the reply. I tried to change the code to something like this `let a = null; let aValue = (a = Constant.projectName) ? a : null;`. It do works, but it will miss the brievity I am trying to achieve. Anyway thankyou as I also have learned a lot from this. +1 for the duck too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and process only a given value.

If `aValue` is `null` or a falsy value, this value is assigned to `anotherValue`, otherwise, it takes the value of `process(aValue)`.

```
anotherValue = (aValue = functionThatReturnsAValue()) && process(aValue);
```

Comment: This works for me. Thankyou very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since aValue is the value returned from executing functionThatReturnsAValue(), You can try this

```
var anotherValue = (functionThatReturnsAValue()) ? process(functionThatReturnsAValue()) : null;
```